# Combing multiple RxJS observables and perform a counting task

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new to Rxjs, and I would like to know if this problem can be solved.

Given an array of 5 observable, each has already emitted some data as below:

ary[0] : { 'a', 'b', 'c' }

ary[1] : { 'g', null }

ary[2] : { '1', 'f', '3', null }

ary[3] : { 'x', 'y', 'z'}

ary[4] : { 'h', 'v' }

I would like to have an new observable that emits value for counting the non-null last elements of these 5 observable. In above case, the first value emitted by the new observable is 3 (c, z, v).

Whenever a new data is emitted from one of the observables, the new observable will emit the counting result too. For example, when

ary[4] : { 'h', 'v' } becomes

ary[4] : { 'h', 'v', null }

the new observable will emit 2 (c ,z ).

Comment: Can we describe your data source like this : https://plnkr.co/edit/e30MpsacNahHy0VUdQc7?p=preview ?

Comment: If you can update your question with a small marble diagram I might help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) with a subsequent `map`:

```js
const baseObs = [
  new Rx.Subject(),
  new Rx.Subject(),
  new Rx.Subject(),
  new Rx.Subject(),
  new Rx.Subject(),
]

const counter$ = Rx.Observable
  .combineLatest(baseObs)
  .map(dataList => dataList.filter(d => d != null).length);
  
counter$.subscribe(
  num => console.log(`Num is ${num}`)
);

baseObs[0].next("a");
baseObs[1].next(null);
baseObs[2].next(null);
baseObs[3].next("z");
baseObs[4].next("v");

setTimeout(() => baseObs[4].next(null), 300);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```